# Set default value in function dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have function dropdownlist, which it have 3 data :

- Inventory
- Asset
- P&L

I want to set default value is "Inventory".

> JavaScript

```
columns: [ 
            { field: "itemType", title:"Item Type", editor: getItem }, ]

function getItem(container, options) {
$('<input name="itemType" required dataTextField="itemType" dataValueField="value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
    .appendTo(container)
    .kendoDropDownList({
        //optionLabel: "Select Item Type",
        dataTextField: "itemType", 
        dataValueField:  "value", 
        filter: "contains",
        autoBind: true,
        dataSource: [
            { itemType:"Inventory"},
            { itemType:"Asset"},
            { itemType:"P&L"},
        ]  

    });
        $('<span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="itemType"></span>').appendTo(container);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my solution:

```
itemType: {editable: true, **defaultValue: "inventory",** validation: {required: {message: "<?php $ehorsDefault->EHORS_DISPLAY_OUTPUT("msgValueIsRequired", $_SESSION['languageID']); ?>"}} },
```